# Batch File: Unknown Error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd created a batch script that will create html files for my site. But it does not seem to work. I'd tried to get the error but I can't

here it is:
http://pastebin.com/r9n31UCS

I used pastebin because you cannot put html tags here.

[Patched from pastebin - no apparent reason for "cannot put HTML tags" comment by OP]

```
@echo off
set n=1
:start
set /a p=n-1
set /a x=n+1
set A=^<html^>
set B=^<head^>
set C=^<title^>
set D=One Piece Episode %n%
set E=^<^/title^>
set F=^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^" src^=^"^/scripts^/jwplayer.js^" ^>^<^/script^>
set G=^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^"^>jwplayer.key^=^"atgAhLbG+xtxBl7CY0CgP8QhQhg2Rb67mVRQ8A^=^=^";^<^/script^>
set H=^<^/head^>
set I=^<body^>
set J=^<center^>
set K=^<b^>Episode %n%^<^/b^> 
set L=^<br ^/^> 
set M=^<div id^=^"myElement^"^>Loading the player...^<^/div^> 
set N=^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^"^> 
set O=jwplayer^(^"myElement^"^).setup^(^{ 
set P=file: ^"episodes^/op^(%n%^).mp4^", 
set Q=image: ^"Nexusserver0019.cloudapp.net/op/back.jpg^" 
set R=height: 360, 
set s=width: 640
set T=^}^)^; 
set U=^<^/script^>
set V=^<a href^=^"ep(%p%).html^"^> Episode %p% ^<^/a^>^&nbsp^&nbsp^&nbsp^&nbsp^&nbsp^<a href^=^"ep(%x%).html^"^> Episode %x% ^<^/a^>
set W=^<^/center^>
set X=^<^/body^>
set Y=^<^/html^>
echo %A% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %B% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %C% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %D% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %E% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %F% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %G% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %H% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %I% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %J% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %K% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %L% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %M% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %N% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %O% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %P% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %Q% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %R% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %S% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %T% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %U% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %V% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %W% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %X% >> ep(%n%).html
echo %Y% >> ep(%n%).html
echo Generating Episode %n% ...
set /a n=n+1
pause
goto start
pause
```

Comment: So - we can conclude it doesn't work - if it did, you'd not be posting a question. Please specify WHAT it does or doesn't do that you EXPECT it to not do or do.

Comment: sorry, but your code is nearly unreadable

Answer (score 2):

Here are the mistakes I see:

### Batch/CMD is case-*in*sensitive regarding variable names.

You use **n** as the episode number, but later you use **N** as a variable for other stuff. In particular, N has redirection operators in it, and this thoroughly confuses cmd.

The first echo command that is attempted expands to this before execution:

```
echo <html> >> ep(<script type="text/javascript"> ).html
```

You can see the obvious problem with multiple redirected outputs there. 
(You could see this for yourself if you commented out the "@echo off" at the beginning of the script.)

### Assignment, Then Echo ??

I don't know why you're assigning the text to variables anyway if all you're going to do is just echo it out. You could replace each SET assignment with ECHO and the append (>>) part and you wouldn't notice the problem previously mentioned.

### Working Version

Here's a version of your script that creates a sequence of HTML files with the nav links in them. I don't have the player stuff to see if it works, but the CMD script does its job well enough.

I replaced the variable **n** with **episode** for slightly better readability. (I did it before doing away with the SET / ECHO repetition.) I also saved the output file in a variable so that if you decided to change it later, you'd only have to change one line, instead of 25.

Also, I noticed that you're using the non-breaking space character entity ref ( ), but leaving off the trailing semicolon. IE might interpret it as you intend (DWIM), but it's wrong. All CE references must end with the semicolon. I changed that, too. The semicolon has to be escaped, also, otherwise cmd.exe misinterprets it.

```
@echo off
set episode=1
:start
set /a p=%episode%-1
set /a x=%episode%+1
set ofile=ep(%episode%).html

echo ^<html^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<head^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<title^>>>%ofile%
echo One Piece Episode %episode%>>%ofile%
echo ^<^/title^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^" src^=^"^/scripts^/jwplayer.js^" ^>^<^/script^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^"^>jwplayer.key^=^"atgAhLbG+xtxBl7CY0CgP8QhQhg2Rb67mVRQ8A^=^=^";^<^/script^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<^/head^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<body^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<center^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<b^>Episode %episode%^<^/b^> >>%ofile%
echo ^<br ^/^> >>%ofile%
echo ^<div id^=^"myElement^"^>Loading the player...^<^/div^> >>%ofile%
echo ^<script type^=^"text^/javascript^"^> >>%ofile%
echo jwplayer^(^"myElement^"^).setup^(^{ >>%ofile%
echo file: ^"episodes^/op^(%episode%^).mp4^", >>%ofile%
echo image: ^"Nexusserver0019.cloudapp.net/op/back.jpg^" >>%ofile%
echo height: 360, >>%ofile%
echo width: 640>>%ofile%
echo ^}^)^; >>%ofile%
echo ^<^/script^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<a href^=^"ep(%p%).html^"^> Episode %p% ^<^/a^>^&nbsp^;^&nbsp^;^&nbsp^;^&nbsp^;^&nbsp^;^<a href^=^"ep(%x%).html^"^> Episode %x% ^<^/a^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<^/center^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<^/body^>>>%ofile%
echo ^<^/html^>>>%ofile%


echo Generating Episode %episode% ...
set /a episode=%episode%+1
pause
goto start
pause
```